# Dynamically changing Open Graph properties for Facebook Like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, prettyphoto

I am using the *jQuery PrettyPhoto* as an image gallery. Each image has it's own facebook-like button on the bottom of the image modal. I'd like to have the image that was liked to appear as the thumbnail on the 'user who clicked like's status update related to liking the image. (Also, I'd like the title to be unique, but I am assuming they can be changed the same way, if at all.)

As of now, the Facebook snippet seems to be scraping the gallery meta properties on load, grabbing the og:title and og:image content that is listed there. I've tried to dynamically change these values whenever a new gallery image is clicked, but it seemed to be using the values of the page loaded meta content (which makes sense).

Is there a way to change what the facebook like button sees as the image it should use on-'like'? Each gallery image is dynamically loaded on the same page, only changing the achor value per image. I've tried a number of ways with no success, but maybe someone has some experience with this or a similar issue.

Thanks for any help or leads!

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't supply any example, I checked with [here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto). As I can see they also use original like button, so the og:title and og:image should be different in each image. Instead of images, can you use html in every popup and put image, your like button etc there?

PS: Or else, you have to dynamically change the title of gallery by javascript, which is not a very idea situation. Facebook will always look for og:title for scrapping data, you can't simply feed it by custom code.

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing in the interest of time. Something akin to what you describe.

I set the href of the like button to point to a directory like gallery/1/12 where 1 and 12 represented the PrettyPhoto Gallery and Photo ID. From there, I had an apache rewrite setup to pass 1 and 12 to a gallery.php page that contained the specific Open Graph properties: title, url, and image. This way facebook was sharing that page's OG.

The og:url was set to this page as well, but on page load, it redirects to the actually gallery url that works.

A little sloppy, but it works as good as I need.